# What is the maximum number of threads we can run in NSOperationQueue simultaneously

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsoperationqueue

It is always being asked in interview how many maximum threads we can run in ios iphone programming simultaneously in `NSOperationQueue` and through GCD async?

Please explain the answer.

Comment: Have you at least done a search first?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount` when you create your operations to let the OS decide the maximum number of operations - it will decide this based on the hardware available and system resources. The number will of course vary depending on device.